# Calculating the distribution of $X-Y$

Tags: probability, distributions, convolution

One can find the distribution of $X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables using this formula

$$f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a-y) f_Y(y) dy$$

I'm wondering how to adapt this formula to find the distribution of $X-Y$. Is that correct?

$$f_{X-Y}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a+y) f_Y(-y) dy$$

Comment: Plug $-Y$ in for $Y$ in the first formula to obtain $f_{X+Y}(a)=f_{X+(-Y)}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a-y) f_{-Y}(y) dy.$ You can easily compute $f_{-Y}$ from $f_Y.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is incorrect.  The correct formula should be
\begin{align}
f_{X - Y}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a + y)f_Y(y)dy, \tag{1}
\end{align}
which is the consequence of
\begin{align}
P[X - Y \leq a] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[X \leq a + y]f_Y(y)dy = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_X(a + y)f_Y(y)dy
\end{align}
and then taking derivative under the integral with respect to $a$ (this is also how the convolution formula for $f_{X + Y}$ is derived).  Of course, when $f_Y$ is symmetric about $0$, then $(1)$ coincides with what you proposed.

Alternatively, suppose you already know the convolution formula
\begin{align}
f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a - y)f_Y(y)dy \tag{2}
\end{align}
for $X + Y$ with independent $X$ and $Y$, and want to derive $f_{X - Y}$ directly from it without computing the CDF then taking derivative as above (that's probably what you really intended given how the question is presented). You can write $X - Y = X + (-Y)$, it then follows by $(2)$ that (note $X$ and $-Y$ are independent given $X$ and $Y$ are):
\begin{align}
f_{X - Y}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a - y)f_{-Y}(y)dy. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Since $f_{-Y}(y) = f_Y(-y)$ (to see this, consider the 1-1 transformation $g(y) = -y$ with Jacobian determinant $-1$), $(3)$ becomes
\begin{align}
f_{X - Y}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a - y)f_Y(-y)dy. \tag{4}
\end{align}
By variable substitution $-y = t$, $(4)$ and $(1)$ are identical.

Answer (score 3):

Retreat to the basics: consider $U:= X-Y, ~X, Y$ being independent. Consider the set $S:=\{(x,y)\mid x-y\leq u\}.$ Therefore the cdf of $U$ is

\begin{align}F_U(u)&=\Pr[U\leq u]\\&=\iint_S f(x, y) ~\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{x-u}^\infty f(x, y) ~\mathrm dy\right) ~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^u f(x, x-z) ~\mathrm dz\right) ~\mathrm dx, ~~~z:= x-y\\&= \int_{-\infty}^u \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, x-z) ~\mathrm dx\right) ~\mathrm dz~~~\textrm{(Fubini's Theorem) };\tag 1\label 1\end{align} from $\eqref 1,$ the pdf of $U$ is \begin{align} f_U(u) &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, x-u) ~\mathrm dx \\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u+y, y) ~\mathrm dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(x-u) ~\mathrm dx\\&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(u+y) \cdot f_Y(y) ~\mathrm dy. \end{align}